# Why can't Libreoffice on FreeBSD save to Google Drive?

Tags: linux, unix, libreoffice, freebsd, google-drive

There are [instructions out there on configuring "Remote Files" in LibreOffice](https://oscollege.com/libreoffice-2/libreoffice-remote-server-introduction/connecting-libreoffice-to-google-drive/).

However, in my case, the Google Drive is not among the available options. Indeed, the instructions say, emphasis mine:

> With version 5.1, LibreOffice has given Windows and Mac users and Mac
> users the ability to access their documents stored on Google Drive
> directly from one of the suite’s applications. **Currently, Drive
> cannot be accessed from a LibreOffice version running on a Linux
> distro or another operating system**.

Alfresco and Sharepoint are available, but not Google Drive... Does anyone one know, why that is -- and whether, maybe, the functionality can be forced (even if partially)?

My LibreOffice is (currently) at 6.4.4.1, built locally from the corresponding [FreeBSD port](https://www.freshports.org/editors/libreoffice).